# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a coxph curve using the below code

```
Cox_carcinoma_data<-coxph(Surv(time,status)~independent_variables,method="breslow")
summary(Cox_carcinoma_data)
plot(Cox_carcinoma_data,conf.int = F,lwd=5,xlab="time", ylab="Survival Probability")
axis(1, xaxp=c(200,1800,16))
axis(2, yaxp=c(0.1,1.0,9))
```

However, I get the below error. I have used this code earlier and it worked fine.I do not understand why it has trouble now.

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it..it is supposed to be

```
plot(survfit(Cox_carcinoma_data),conf.int = F,lwd=5,xlab="time", ylab="Survival Probability")
axis(1, xaxp=c(200,1800,16))
axis(2, yaxp=c(0.1,1.0,9))
```

Thanks.